# How do I revert back an element to default state when I click a div? (jQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a navigation menu. There is a Toggle for the menu to drop down. The default state of the toggle is blue and when the drop-down menu is out, it turns red.

But when I click one of the li items, it doesn't revert back to it's default state which is blue, it just stays red.

My question is: How do I make it go back to it's default state when I click on the li items? I want it to do the Rotating thing as well as changing the color back to blue when it reverts back to its default state.

Here is a JSFiddle link https://jsfiddle.net/61g4std1/9/

Thank you for your time people :)

```
/*===================
---- Menu Rotate ----
===================*/
$(document).ready(function() {

var rotation = 0;
$('#menutoggle').click(function() {
    rotation += -180;
    $(this).css({'-webkit-transform' : 'rotate('+ rotation +'deg)',
             '-moz-transform' : 'rotate('+ rotation +'deg)',
             '-ms-transform' : 'rotate('+ rotation +'deg)',
             'transform' : 'rotate('+ rotation +'deg)'});
});

$('#menutoggle').click(function() {
$(this).toggleClass('rotated');
});

$('#menutoggle').click(function () {
   $(this).toggleClass("hov");
});

})

/*=====================
---- Menu Dropdown ----
=====================*/
$(function() {
    $("#menutoggle").click(function () {
        $(this).toggleClass("#mobilemenu");
    });


    $('#menutoggle').click(function(){
        $('#mobilemenu').toggle('blind');
    });


    $("#mobilemenu li").click(function() {
        $("#mobilemenu li").removeClass('hover');
        $(this).addClass('hover');
    });

    $('a#hide, a#hide2').click(function(){
        $('#mobilemenu').hide();
    })


});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to fire your event handler manually (Or attach the correct classes) to your `#menutoggle` element in order for it to change back blue. [Here](https://jsfiddle.net/61g4std1/12/) is an updated jsfiddle:

```
/*===================
---- Menu Rotate ----
===================*/
var rotation = 0;
$(document).ready(function() {

$('#menutoggle').click(function() {
    rotation += -180;
    $(this).css({'-webkit-transform' : 'rotate('+ rotation +'deg)',
                 '-moz-transform' : 'rotate('+ rotation +'deg)',
                 '-ms-transform' : 'rotate('+ rotation +'deg)',
                 'transform' : 'rotate('+ rotation +'deg)'});
    $(this).toggleClass('rotated');
    $(this).toggleClass("hov");
});

})

/*=====================
---- Menu Dropdown ----
=====================*/
$(function() {
    $("#menutoggle").click(function () {
        $(this).toggleClass("#mobilemenu");
    });


    $('#menutoggle').click(function(){
        $('#mobilemenu').toggle('blind');
    });


    $("#mobilemenu li").click(function() {
        $("#mobilemenu li").removeClass('hover');
        $(this).addClass('hover');
        rotation += -180;
        $('#menutoggle').css({'-webkit-transform' : 'rotate('+ rotation +'deg)',
                 '-moz-transform' : 'rotate('+ rotation +'deg)',
                 '-ms-transform' : 'rotate('+ rotation +'deg)',
                 'transform' : 'rotate('+ rotation +'deg)'});
        $('#menutoggle').toggleClass('rotated');
        $('#menutoggle').toggleClass("hov");
    });

    $('a#hide, a#hide2').click(function(){
        $('#mobilemenu').hide();
    })


});
```

Comment: Thank you, this helped a lot :) Thanks for also cleaning up my code

Comment: @billybobjones for more clear code you can wrap .css() to one function it give you advantage of maintainable code and code duplication

Answer (score 1):

add

```
$('#menutoggle').trigger('click');
```

to

```
$("#mobilemenu li").click(function() { ...
```

Answer (score 1):

you can just add this to your code and it will work fine :

```
$("li").click(function () {
   $("#menutoggle").css( "background-color", "blue" );
});
```